# Show header in show_transfers

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

How can I enable header in `show_transfers` command? It's printing a lot of columns without any info.

Is it possible to show names of those columns like this?

```
txid     | Height  |  Timestamp  | Amount | PaymentID  | Change | Fee      | Destinations Note
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<b06xxx>   1403333    2017-10-10   1.000    fAxxxx       11       0.004400   fsfsdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Spam because you can't post with so few characters even though it is a correct answer.

Comment: :/ pitty I'm not c++ guy. Should be pretty easy to make a commit.